# How to randomly generate an Oct-Tuple with SML

Tags: c++, sml, smlnj

Edit: Here is the code I have so far for generating the Patient Oct-Tuples.
(*thanks Anon for giving me the bost on how to calculate weighted probability/setting the seed*)

```
fun genPatients(x:int) =
let
val seed=let
val m=Date.minute(Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now()))
val s=Date.second(Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now()))
in Random.rand(m,s)
end;   
val survivalrate = ref(1)
val numl = ref(1)
val td = ref(1)
val xray = ref(false)
val count= ref(0)
val emnum= ref(1000)
val ageList = [1, 2, 3, 3];
val xrayList=[false,true];
val age = Random.randRange (0, 3) seed;(* random age*)
val nextInt1 = Random.randRange(0, 1)(* random xray*)
val r1 = Random.rand(1,1)
val nextInt2 = Random.randRange(1, 10000000)(* random td*)
val r2 = Random.rand(1,1)
val r1hold= ref(1);
in
while !count < x do
(
count:= !count + 1;
List.nth(ageList, age);
r1hold:= nextInt1 r1;
td:= nextInt2 r2;
(!emnum,age,survivalrate,numl,[],[],xray,td);
emnum:= !emnum + 1
)
end;
```

My question now is now how to go about indexing a boolean list?

Answer (score 1):

So I was looking for some help defining my Oct-tuple to finish up my project and lo and behold I find someone posting the entirety of my project hoping for a handout answer. Not only that, but I'm almost certain we're in the same class, and you think posting this the night before the morning the project is due is what a responsible student does? Pretty sure nobody on SO is gonna do your homework for you anyway, in fact I'm not even sure it's allowed.

Maybe do some work and then ask for help when you've actually done anything. Or maybe in the next phase try a little harder.

EDIT: I'll give you something to get you started.

To calculate weighted probability you need a seed.

```
val seed=let
val m=Date.minute(Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now()))
val s=Date.second(Date.fromTimeLocal(Time.now()))
in Random.rand(m,s)
end;
```

Here's one. Then you can calculate probability, at least for the age, like this:

```
val ageList = [1, 2, 3, 3];
val ageInt = Random.randRange (0, 3) seed;
List.nth(ageList, ageInt)
```

This was how I decided to do the weighted probability portion, you can equate this to the other weighted sections if you're creative. Good luck.